# extended xsd for xml with multiple namespaces

Tags: spring, xsd

Hey, im trying to open my XML schema for different namespaces, this seems to work but all the default namespace elements now are invalid.

Thank you in advance. I'm trying to achieve the same schema extension mechanism as done in Spring (i.E.: spring-beans.2.5.xsd) they open the `bean` definition also for `##other` and this works!

I added an [example of these three files](http://rapidshare.com/files/351047548/example_with_other_namespace_xsd.zip.html) for easy access to a zip archive and uploaded it to the one-click-hoster rapidshare.

Whats my fault?

**example-list.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://www.example.org/schema/list"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/schema/list">

  <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" />

  <xs:complexType name="ExampleListModelType">
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:group ref="ExampleListGroup" />
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:group name="ExampleListGroup">
    <xs:choice>
      <xs:element name="foo" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="bar" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="baz" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:any namespace="##other" processContents="strict" />
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:group>

  <xs:element name="action-list" type="ExampleListModelType" />
</xs:schema>
```

**custom-example-list.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns="http://www.example.org/schema/custom" elementFormDefault="qualified"
 targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/schema/custom">
  <xs:element name="eek" type="xs:string" />
</xs:schema>
```

**example-list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<action-list xmlns="http://www.example.org/schema/list" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:custom="http://www.example.org/schema/custom"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.example.org/schema/list example-list.xsd
    http://www.example.org/schema/custom custom-example-list.xsd">
  <custom:eek></custom:eek>
  <bar></bar>
</action-list>
```

**The error**

`Invalid content was found starting with element 'bar'. One of '{foo, bar, baz, WC[##other:"http://www.example.org/schema/list"]}' is expected`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, that was a hard one. It's been a long time since I had to just keep making random-ish changes to xsd and validate to see what happens. :)

Add `elementFormDefault="qualified"` as an attribute to your `<xs:schema>` tag in `example-list.xsd` and it all validates. I'm still a bit confused as to why that is needed.

Comment: Totally crazy, thank you very very much! If you ever find out, why this is necessary please send me a note =)

Comment: When `elementFormDefault="unqualified"` (which is the default) in example-list.xsd, it means the local elements (the elements not directly defined under schema) should not be qualified in the instance XML, i.e. they should not have their namespaces defined. But in your exmaple-list.xml, the local element bar has its namespace defined as `http://www.example.org/schema/list` by virtue of defining a default namespace on its parent (action-list).

Comment: To test this out you can add `xmlns=""` to the bar element in the example-list.xml. This would make the element belong to null namespace and the XML should validate.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is in your **custom-example-list.xsd**. You define the element "eek" to be in no namespace.

Change `xmlns:balvi="http://www.example.org/schema/custom"` to `xmlns="http://www.example.org/schema/custom"` in that schema.

**Edit:** Ok, so if you fixed that, here it gets tricky. The only thing I can think of is that because you specified `##other`, only an element from *outside* your target namespace must appear there. But then you have this in a choice with elements from your target namespace. I cannot see anything in the spec that disambiguates this situation.

Perhaps you might want to change that choice to a simple sequence and see if it works then. If so, you know what's wrong. If it still breaks, it's possible that your schema include is failing.

Comment: ok, thank you - i corrected this (updated question), but unfortunately this doesn't help with my problem.

Comment: it still breaks with `sequence` instead of `choice`, i don't understand why it breaks. i use the schema include mechanism in the same way that spring does.